# how kamailio logs are going to print?

Tags: kamailio

how kamailio logs are going to print ? kamailio work as intermediate. how it is possible to decrypt the logs and then print on kamailio.The logs of kamailio is giving the idea of error and also for monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable kamailio logs with with below syntax in kamailio.cfg file:

```
xlog("L_INFO","INFO: INVITE from main Request from $fu to $ou\n");
```

You can find kamailio logs by following command:

```
tailf /var/log/messages | grep kamailio
```